# Mysql Login wildcard not working on a single machine

Tags: mysql, odbc

I am trying to login into mysql on a pc and I just can't figure out what is wrong with it.

The error:
Acces denied for user 'username'@'xxx.xx.xxx.xx'

There are 15-20 connections already made to this mysql server with the same user and the same password.

What I've tried:

- Checking username, password, ip and port is correct.
- Disabling firewall
- Disabling antivirus
- Using heidisql to check connection. Returns same error
- Using odbc to test connection. It returns successful connection on test. But connecting to it with our application returns the same error as above.
- Using different versions of ODBC. Same error
- Connecting from different IP's. Same error
- PC Runs windows 10 so I checked if this was the issue by trying 2 windows 10 machines both work.
- Checked that the user can connect from anywhere in mysql (wildcard tag %). This is true the user set as reachable from anywhere %.
- Tested if the above is really true and it is true I can connect from multiple
  pc's from multiple locations
- Checked if it has to do with mysql server. The one where
  it does not work is 5.5.30. I tried connecting to 5.6.23 and THIS
  works.
- Tried connecting with Mysql Workbench and I can succesfully connect and see my database.

Any suggestions? I don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some strange reason the user that is connecting is denied access. We tried a different user and that one was allowed. Both users are identical except for the usernames. No clue why this works but it works.